# How can we implement a registration by invitation in existing application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

My application supports normal registration for admin roles and registration by invite for team members. Admins can successfully register themselves. Login functionality is also working fine. I am using jwt for token generation and `AuthGuards` to protect private routes.

Need some help on how I can send an invitation url to users? (nodemailer already configured and working). More concerned about url generation.

Can someone help me?
The application backend is in nestjs and frontend is in angular 8.
Currently I am testing apis through postman.

Thanks in advance,
Ajinkya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Create a database entity `invitation-token` with one column `token` (randomly generated UUID, e.g. with this [uuid lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)). Set it to self-delete entries after 24 hours. (e.g. [TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) in mongodb)

2) Create an endpoint that allows registration with a query param `invitation-token`, 
e.g. `/registration?invitation-token=Usa67Nsus78`. It only allows registration if the given token exists in the table created in step 1).

3) Create an `invite` endpoint that takes a mail address as input. It creates a new token in the `invitation-token` table and sends an email to the given address with a link to the endpoint in 2)

Comment: It's better to send an email field on params at step 2 because you can check if the email exists and then redirect him to the registering page. If an email exists just update the database to make sure he is invited and has access.
It is important when the user receives multi-invitation links.
You can also do this process by saving the email address on the invitation-token entity!